# Как получить lua таблицу в Си коде?

Tags: c, lua

К примеру у меня есть скрипт на lua:

```
return {
  version = 1.0
}
```

Который я загружаю в Си коде:

```
if (!luaL_loadfile(state, argv[1]) && !lua_pcall(state, 0, 0, 0)) {
```

А как получить доступ к этой таблице? Есть функции вроде `get_global` и `get_local`, но они не подходять (по понятным причинам) в этой ситуации. Я, изначально, думал, что при запуске `lua_pcall` я должен получить возвращаемую таблицу сразу на стек, но в этом я ошибался.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не прошло и полминуты как я сам нашел ответ на вопрос: у меня был не верный вызов `lua_pcall` - нужно вторым аргументом выставить 1. Это число возврашаемых значений, так что мы получим на стэк нашу таблицу.

Оставляю этот ответ сдесь - может пригодится кому-то